# Can't insert into my sql table

Tags: php, mysql, post

I get no errors with this code but i can't insert this row on my project table.
Is the problem in my date?

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["username"];
if ( isset( $_POST["name"] )) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
}
if ( isset( $_POST["description"] ) ) {
    $description = $_POST["description"];
}
if ( isset( $_POST["final"] ) ) {
        $final = $_POST["final"];
}
if ( isset( $_POST["goal"] ) ) {
        $goal = $_POST["goal"];
}
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project (name, description, final_date, funds, admin, goal) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$final', '0', '$user', '$goal'");
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Are you sure there is no error? Turn them on at the beginning by: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: do you have a mysql connection open?

Comment: Yes, there is no errors. In the end of my file i put echo "Created with success" but when i go to my table there's nothing in there

Comment: Maybe try to echo the $sql, and then manually submit it to the mysql database. Just for testing...

Comment: yes, all my connections are ok, that's why im confused...

Comment: You did not close the values command properly with a `)`. Also you should use `mysqli_query()`

Comment: ..and error reporting would have spotted that ^

Comment: its hard to debug when you don't create a query string. get use to doing that, then you can echo it and try it on the command line or phpmyadmin

Comment: @Dagon I rather like bugs myself. The "chocolate covered" ones.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a closing `)` to your `INSERT INTO` statement.

The correct statement looks like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO project (name, description, final_date, funds, admin, goal) 
VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$final', '0', '$user', '$goal');");
```

BTW, you should not use `mysql_*` anymore. Instead, the usage of `mysqli_*` or PDO is recommended.